# How to make a magnified inset of a map plot with ggmagnify and ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, tidyverse

For one of the past week's `tidytuesday` challenge, the one where `Tornado` dataset was analyzed, I tried to practice `ggmagnify` package with `ggplot2` to make a magnified inset map of Texas with the US map. So, let me write down the code to demonstrate what I have achieved so far, which will be followed by the question I am inquiring on.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(sf)
library(rnaturalearth)
library(rnaturalearthdata)
library(bertin)
library(usmap)
library(maps)
library(showtext)
library(showtextdb)
library(ggtext)
library(cowplot)
library(ggmagnify)


tornados <- readr::read_csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/rfordatascience/tidytuesday/master/data/2023/2023-05-16/tornados.csv')
state_names_df <- tibble(state = state.name) %>%
  bind_cols(tibble(abb = state.abb)) %>% 
  bind_rows(tibble(state = "District Of Columbia", abb = "DC")) %>%
  as.data.frame()

maps_states_df <- st_as_sf(map("state", plot = FALSE, fill = TRUE)) %>%
  mutate(ID = str_to_title(ID)) 

us_geo_data <- state_names_df %>%
  left_join(maps_states_df, by = c("state" = "ID"))


tornados_acrros_us <- ggplot(us_geo_data) +
  geom_sf(aes(geometry = geom), linewidth = 0.1) +
  geom_point(data = tornados %>% filter(!st %in% c("VI", "DC", "AK", "PR", "HI")), aes(x = slon, y = slat), size = 0.2, color = "darkgreen", alpha = 0.2) +
  ggthemes::theme_map()
```

This code produced the following map:

[image]

Now, what I want to achieve, as I mentioned above, to plot an inset map of Texas with `ggmagnify` package I would like to practice on. Here is the code I have tried to do that.

```
tornados_acrros_us + geom_magnify(from = us_geo_data %>% filter(abb == "TX"),
                                  to =  c(-125, -98, 10, 30))
```

However, this threw an error saying that

```
Warning messages:
1: In min(from$x) : No missing arguments for min; Returning inf
2: In min(from$y) : No missing arguments for min; Returning inf
3: In max(from$x) : No missing arguments for max; Returning -inf
4: In max(from$y) : No missing arguments for max; Returning -inf
5: Removed 51 rows containing missing values (`geom_magnify()`).
```

I could not find a solution on making the map I am aiming for and therefore, I would like to appreciate any assistance from you to solve this solution. Thank you beforehand.

Comment: Check the examples in the README file: https://github.com/hughjonesd/ggmagnify#maps-experimental (try using `aes(from = abb == "TX")` inside `geom_magnify()` instead). Also note that maps are experimental in ggmagnify at the moment so it may not work as you are expecting.

Comment: that's what my code above is based on. It does not work either.

Comment: the logic behind that is the same. And, I have tried that too. The above code is reproducible I guess. So, if you run the code based on the example given in the package's documentation, you will most probably see that it does not work either. Yet, thanks for the suggestions.

Comment: I ran the examples in the README and they didn't work until I re-installed {ggmagnify} using the most recent dev version from GitHub. Which version are you using? It's also possibly related to this open bug: https://github.com/hughjonesd/ggmagnify/issues/15 since you have data in a layer for the points.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the issue here is that your `us_geo_data` is only a data frame not an `sf` object. We can fix this using a `right_join()` instead of a `left_join()`:

```r
tornados <- readr::read_csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/rfordatascience/tidytuesday/master/data/2023/2023-05-16/tornados.csv')
state_names_df <- tibble(state = state.name) %>%
  bind_cols(tibble(abb = state.abb)) %>% 
  bind_rows(tibble(state = "District Of Columbia", abb = "DC")) %>%
  as.data.frame()
maps_states_df <- st_as_sf(map("state", plot = FALSE, fill = TRUE)) %>%
  mutate(ID = str_to_title(ID)) 
us_geo_data <- right_join(maps_states_df, state_names_df, by = c("ID" = "state"))
```

Then plotting:

```r
tornados_across_us <- ggplot(us_geo_data) +
  geom_sf(linewidth = 0.1) +
  geom_point(data = filter(tornados, !st %in% c("VI", "DC", "AK", "PR", "HI")) ,
            aes(x = slon, y = slat), size = 0.2, color = "darkgreen", alpha = 0.2) +
  ggthemes::theme_map()
tornados_across_us

tornados_across_us + geom_magnify(aes(from = abb == "TX"),
                    to = c(-125, -98, 10, 30), 
                    shadow = TRUE, linewidth = 1, colour = "orange2",
                    shape = "outline", 
                    aspect = "fixed", 
                    expand = 0)
```

which gives:

[image: map of usa]

Note that, this only worked using the most recent dev version of {ggmagnify} installed from GitHub. You can play around with the values in `to` or the limits to position the inset map a bit better.

Comment: I do accept your proposed solution and thank you very much for providing such a detailed answer. If you have time, I have one side question, which is about the distinction between right_join and left_join you mentioned above. Tbh, I have not realized such a distinction previously. To elaborate on that, if I did not get you wrong, the right_join function enables the sf value to preserve its format as sf by not converting it to a dataframe and that's the trick along with updating the ggmagnify to its recent version, right?

Comment: Yes, the class of output from a left or right join inherits from the left argument (as far as I'm aware), so `left_join(x, y)` isn't always equal to `right_join(y, x)`. In your case, `y` is an sf object (and dataframe), whereas `x` is only a dataframe. I think ggmagnify is expecting an sf object, when using `geom_sf()`.